# Error occurred after saving a script file

Tags: r

So .. this just happened out of nowhere. I always pressed Ctrl + S to save my R script files, but this afternoon when I saved my file, this error showed up. Does anyone know what happened? It seems that somehow it ran a part of my codes. The file is saved though.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Were you also holding down shift? The short cut in R Studio to source the current document is `Ctrl+Shift+S` and it's looks pretty clear in the console that your file was sourced. So double check that there's nothing pressing a control key.

Comment: you probably checked the "source on save" box